# Deleting all subdirs except ones that match a certain pattern

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, globbing

I would like to delete all sub-directories and files in a given directory except directories that match a certain pattern:

```
example_dir/model-*/gen-*/share/**
```

General setup:
I generated several models (> 100) with each having >=1 generation(s).
Within those models (e.g., `example_dir/model-0/gen-0/`) are several directories and sub-directories.

Desired result:
I would like to delete all directories and files except the ones that match:

```
example_dir/model-*/gen-*/share/
```

Within each single model/gen/ it would be something like this?:

```
rm -rf !(share)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I entirely understand your question,
and I’m not sure what follow-up questions make sense. 
One thing I’m wondering is, if you have a directory tree like

```
example_dir
|-- model-0
|   |-- gen-0
|   |   |-- share
|   |   |-- trash
|   |   |   |-- more_trash
|   |   |-- file123.txt
|   |-- grandfather
|-- platypus
foo
```

is it sufficient to delete `example_dir/model-0/gen-0/trash`
(and its contents), or do you also want to delete
`example_dir/model-0/grandfather`, `example_dir/platypus` and `foo`? 
And how about `example_dir/model-0/gen-0/file123.txt`?

If you want to delete `trash` (and its contents) and `file123.txt`, try

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -rf example_dir/model-*/gen-*/!(share)
```

If you want to delete `trash` (and its contents)
but preserve `file123.txt`, try

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -rf example_dir/model-*/gen-*/!(share)/
```

(adding a `/` after `!(share)`).

Either way, look over the output carefully,
and, if you’re sure it’s what you want,
run the command again without the `echo`.

If you also want to delete top-level directories other than `example_dir`,
first-level directories that don’t match the `model-*` pattern,
or second-level directories that don’t match the `gen-*` pattern,
please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I think rm -rf example_dir/model-*/gen-*/!(share) is what I need. Thank you! 
I will run a test on a fake-directory first. The directory tree only has sub directories beside share. Otherwise it is always example_dir/model-*/gen-*/